# rsync file copy including files that change

Tags: rsync, mirror, lftp

I have to copy files between 2 servers using rsync (the network is slow). Can mirroring/ FXP with lftp be used here? Also there will be a continuous flow of files in the source directory & the delta files also need to be copied to the destination directory.

Source hostname: ftprepo.armt.com.my, port 23,path: /, user id & password
Destination hostname: 192.168.12.240, port: NA, path: /tmp, user id & password

Comment: I am assuming that with delta files you mean that there are changed files?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes, you can use `lftp`.

But since it looks like you are backing up a running system, which will include changed (log-)files, you are IMHO better of sticking with `rsync`, which handles changed files by sending (compressed) deltas, not by uploading complete new files.

You can use a script that repeatedly runs rsync. The first `rsync` will take long time (determined by the network speed and size of the source), the second and following runs much less time as only changed, added information is being sent. `lftp` will unlikely be significantly faster on the first "transfer" and slower on the following ones.

You might also want to look at [`rdiff-backup`](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/), which usses the rsync protocol underneath, but also can preserve deltas to roll-back to previous states (at the cost of extra disc space on the destination host).